# Cannot instantiate Object for ActiveX control in JavaScript: get 429 error

Tags: javascript, .net-4.0, activex, webmatrix

I created an ActiveX control (code only e.g. ZPLPrint.cs) that I compiled as a library into a dll using the csc command in the .Net 4.xxx  directory.  Then I registered the dll using 
regasm ZPLPrint.dll /tlb /codebase .  I'm using WebMatrix to build the control and also using it to run IE10.  My OS is Windows 8.  In my sitelayout.cshtml (in WebMatrix) I have the following JavaScript embedded in the head section:
        script type="text/javascript"
                    var x = new ActiveXObject("ABCActiveXPrint.ZPLPrint");

There is more to the script but I can't get past creating the object above.  I get the following error message:
“SCRIPT429: Automation server can't create object”.  This will ultimately be run on Windows Mobile 6.5 CE.  Am I on the right track here or should I be considering another approach?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the browser was preventing the control from executing due to its security settings.  Since I was developing locally, I simply added localhost to the list of trusted sites and was able to get past the error.